# How to handle parameters in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I have parameters defined under intent and It still ask me to enter size and color. I am puzzled how can I handle these variables?. When both of the variable is recorded before page is getting active how can I show the confirmation message without collecting the data again.

[image]

any hint?

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [order intent with intent parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/build-agent#create_an_order_intent_with_intent_parameters). In the documentation you can see that the sample created Parameter ID with entity type of custom entity type and system entity type.

> You need an intent that is matched when the end-user requests a new shirt order. This intent should also optionally capture the desired shirt color and/or size provided by the end-user in case they provide that info up front